# Changing plugs on Kenmore dryers

Tags: wiring

I have a Kenmore dryer with a 3 wire slanted plug.  I was given a much newer Kenmore dryer but it has a 4 wire plug, with 2 straaight, 1 90 degree, and 1 round. Can I change it and put the 3 wire plug on and will it work and be safe?

Location Oregon.

Answer (score 1):

Take the 3-wire cord off of your old dryer and use it. When you look at it, it should be flat with the three wires. These should line up with the three main connectors on your new dryer. Put the center one into the center connector, while the other two can go to either side. Make sure everything is snug. Have no fear as this is done all of the time. Your dryer will work with either cord, depending on the outlet on the wall.

This is how it should look in the dryer:

[image: Pulled from electrical.about.com]